# Programmatically change DataGrid column width to longest size of cell content

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I'm looking for examples how to programmatically change a DataGrid column width to Auto while ignoring the text from the column header (if the header content is longer than the longest content from column cells).

Comment: you ar eusing DataGridView in Windows form ?

Comment: Set DataGrridColum Width="Auto"  not need to set in code-behind . Based on header size it will be resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use property [sizeToCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlengthunittype(v=vs.95).aspx) (from MSDN)

like this for single column :

```
grid.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.SizeToCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `Header` property of column in the XAML markup like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="some very long header some very long header  some very long header" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="short" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

..you could set it programmatically once the `DataGrid` has been loaded:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" Loaded="dg_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="short" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dg.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(dg.Columns[0].ActualWidth);
    dg.Columns[0].Header = "some very long header some very long header  some very long header";
}
```

Then the width of the column will be based on the cell content only but not on the length of the header.